# Implementation of isInstanceOf[T] in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand how Scala's `isInstanceOf[T]` works.

What would be the equivalent code of this function in Scala?

```
/**
 * @param theClass The predicate evaluates to true for instances of this class
 *                 or one of its subclasses.
 */
 public IsInstanceOf(Class<?> theClass) {
   this.theClass = theClass;
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: `def IsInstanceOf(theClass: Class[_]) { this.theClass = theClass }`?

Comment: Hi - thank you! I tried running this function and it threw an error. Here's the code:

class User {
  def InstanceOf(theClass: Class[_]) = this.getClass() == theClass
}

Comment: what is `this.theClass = theClass` supposed to mean?

Comment: Even if you change the `=` to `equals` or `==`, it's not what you want. `instanceof` (Java) or `isInstanceOf` respects subtypes.

Comment: @user43624, your code does not contain a method/function, it contains a constructor of `IsInstanceOf` class. I strongly suspect that this class implements `Predicate` or something and the actual logic is contained in some method form that interface. If it is so, you have to provide its code instead.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Please take a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252855/a-method-in-scala-that-takes-no-arguments-and-uses-a-generic-type

Comment: @user43624, well, you already got a lot of useful answers there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isInstanceOf` in Scala is implemented the same way as `instanceof` operator is implemented in Java. They both translate to the `instanceof` JVM bytecode instruction.

In other words, they're both actually implemented by the JVM, not the Scala/Java compiler and exact implementation is a possibly platform-dependent detail.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What I'm looking is to understand how to call a method with a generic type that takes no parameters. I tried different method definitions and every time I'd fail not quite understanding what I did wrong.

Comment: @user43624 I think it would be best for you to create a separate question about this with all the needed details.