# A method in Scala that takes no arguments and uses a generic type

Tags: scala, generics

I'm trying to write a method in Scala that will take no arguments and will use a generic type to perform some logic in the method that will return output solely based on the generic type (similar to `asInstanceOf[T]` or `isInstanceOf[T]`).

It should be something like this:

```
val myObj = new MyClass
myObj.instanceOf[MyClass]
// returns true
```

This is what I thought may work.

```
class MyClass {
  def instanceOf[Class[_]]: Bool = {
    // ???
  }
}
```

How do I implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: hard to understand what you're asking — what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Short version: I'm trying to understand how `asInstanceOf[T]` works by implementing it by myself. Long version: I'm trying to be exotic with the code, nothing that I actually need right now, it's more about learning how some internal things work in Scala. The method I wanted to write is a method that takes no parameters, just a generic type. Then I'd use the generic type inside the method body to perform some logic eg. cast types manually, converts an object to a barcode, or a serial number. 

`val item = new Item("Sample product")` 
`item.to[BarCode]` 
`item.to[SerialCode]` etc ...

Comment: Wow you guys are amazing. You have already answered while I was typing the previous comment. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grab the type that was passed in by using ClassTags and use that.

A contrived example of what is asked in the title would be:

```
class Foo(name: String) {
  def nameMatches[T: ClassTag]() =
    classTag[T].runtimeClass.getName == name
}

new Foo("java.lang.String").nameMatches[String] //> res1: Boolean = true
new Foo("boolean").nameMatches[Boolean]         //> res2: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for the example you gave.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class MyClass { 
  def instanceOf[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[this.type] <:< typeOf[T] 
}
```

Note that when you extend `MyClass` you will need to override `instanceOf` to get correct behaviour. Else you will get this:

```
scala> class MySubClass extends MyClass
defined class MySubClass

scala> (new MySubClass).instanceOf[MyClass]  // works
res3: Boolean = true

scala> (new MySubClass).instanceOf[Any]  // works
res4: Boolean = true

scala> (new MySubClass).instanceOf[MySubClass]  // doesn't work
res5: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example of a generic method would be the standard library's `implicitly`, which you can trivially implement yourself:

```
def implicitly[T](implicit ev: T) = ev
```

so you can do things like look up type class instances:

```
trait Show[T] { def shows(t: T): String }
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
implicit val personShow = new Show[Person] { def show(p: Person) = s"${p.name} @ ${p.age} years" }

implicitly[Show[Person]]
```

this is useful in two cases:

1. you define a non-trivial type class instance using `def` (i.e. you generically "generate" type class instances from instances of other type classes) and you're not sure you got it right:

   ```
   implicit def terriblyNonTrivialTCInstance[T, U, V, W, Ñ](implicit ev1: Foo, ev2: Bar, ev3: Baz, ...): FooTC[T, U] = ...

   implicitly[FooTC[MyType1, MyType2]]  // compile error if the above definition is badly constructed
   ```
2. your method takes an implicit evidence but instead of using an `implicit` arg list, you prefer to use a type bound, and later you'd like to grab an instance of the type class using `implicitly`:

   ```
   def myMethod[T: FooTC[T, Int]](t: T) = {
     val ev = implicitly[FooTC[T, Int]]
     ev.doSmth(t)
   }
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   def myMehtod[T](t: T)(implicit ev: FooTC[T, Int]) = {
     ev.doSmth(t)
   }
   ```

P.S. in the stdlib, `implicitly` is implemented like this:

```
@inline def implicitly[T](implicit e: T) = e
```